# Android get google user Birthday and Gender

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus, google-api-java-client

Main task is to get users Age and Gender on current device (for ads targeting).

---

*I knew that this question could be possible duplicate, but none of posted answers didn't help me.*

---

From my code i'm getting correct users Name but birthday = null, gender = 0.
Tested on my test device with valid Google Account with public Birthday and Gender.

---

```
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1009;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private int connectionFailedCounter;

private void googleSignIn() {
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .build();

    googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...
    googleSignIn();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
        if (googleApiClient == null)
            googleSignIn();
        else if (!googleApiClient.isConnecting())
            googleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    if (googleApiClient != null && googleApiClient.isConnected())
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "google+ connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(googleApiClient);
    if (currentPerson != null) {
//NotificationManager is my own class, 
//sendNotification(Context context, Class classToOpenOnClick, String title, String message)
        NotificationManager.sendNotification(this, null, currentPerson.getName().getFamilyName(),
                    String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "bir = %s, gen = %d", currentPerson.getBirthday(), currentPerson.getGender()));
    }
    else Toast.makeText(this, "getCurrentPerson = null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.e(TAG, "connection failed (" + connectionResult.getErrorCode() + ")");
    Toast.makeText(this, "google+ failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
        try {
            connectionFailedCounter++;
            if (connectionFailedCounter < 2)
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {

        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Person currentPerson  = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(googleApiClient);

            NotificationManager.sendNotification(this, null, currentPerson.getName().getFamilyName(),
                    String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "bir = %s, gen = %d", currentPerson.getBirthday(), currentPerson.getGender()));

            if (!googleApiClient.isConnected())
                googleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to log the currentPerson.getBirthday() and currentPerson.getGender(), is it null and 0? if no then something is wrong with the sendNotification() EDIT: or the time that you call it, those happens async that means there is a chance that the time you calling the getBirthday or whatever you haven't taken back the response

Comment: @Tony currentPerson.getBirthday() is String, and in is null, Gender is int, and it is 0. sendNotification works fine. I have to send notification instead Log, because this functional works only in release app mode, so i can't debug it.

Comment: are you sure the user gives access to birthday and gender?

Comment: @Tony i wrote this. I can attach screenshot with google plus profile with public access to gender & birthday.

Comment: try not to use the String.format ,use currentPerson.getBirthday().toString() instead, don't know the answer but just some ideas that may help

Comment: Plus API seems to return ageRange only, if you need the exact birthday you should use People API with appropriate scope.